# It should be possible to make edits after casting a reopen vote not count toward the reopen review

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, vote-to-reopen

When submitting an edit after casting a reopen vote, the checkbox "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening"  can't be unchecked:

[image]

Feature request: Allow users to uncheck "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening"  when submitting an edit after casting a reopen vote.

One major place where this ends up becoming a problem is if one believes that a question in its current state doesn't violate any site rules, but there are some minor grammar or formatting edits that are necessary. Any edit made with the box checked will show to reviewers as one that attempts to reopen the post, and will trigger showing the revisions by default. What often happens is that reviewers only see the minor edit and review to leave closed, without checking the question before the edit to see if it still violates any site guidelines. When making an edit before voting to reopen, there's a way to mark the edit as not attempting to reopen the post, but that's not so when editing after voting to reopen.

Comment: If you've cast a reopen vote you already thought the question should be reopened in the state it was in. You're editing it so that's no longer the case? Why? You can always retract your reopen vote first if you made a mistake.

Comment: @RobertLongson eg editing to fix a typo

Comment: IRRC it is only disabled if the question already has an edit pending that was marked as resolving the problems, and you are editing over it - am I misremembering?

Comment: Why cast a reopen vote if you don't want it reopened?

Comment: Are you positive that submitting an edit with this box in its disabled state still submits the edit as "significant"? I was under the impression that the only time an edit is marked as significant (in the timeline or in review) is when an edit voluntarily checks this box before a post is in the queue.

Comment: @RobertLongson See the added paragraph. Keeping the box checked may negate the effort toward reopening.

Comment: This shouldn't be difficult to test in order to verify; just need someone to VTR a closed post, observe how it appears in Reopen queue before an edit, and then observe it again afterwards. Based on what I can see in [an already completed review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/31833314) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeA23.png)), this is moot, because **all edits since closure** appear to be shown in the queue, _not_ edits since the question was added to review. If this is accurate, it means your pre-VTR edit would appear regardless.

Comment: Sonic is correct. Also it's poor UX.

Comment: @RobertLongson I want it reopened. But the edit doesn't address the original close reason.

Answer (score 5):

> What often happens is that reviewers only see the minor edit and review to leave closed

This isn't what happens, at least not with the current system. At the top of the review, it shows a list of the edit summaries that were made since closure. Underneath is a diff that is a combination of all those edits. Take this [review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/425395) for example. I made a small edit to the body, and the review diff shows all the changes:

[image: Diff showing two edits]

It can feel weird to edit a post and see that box be checked. But the current behavior works just fine. It's a good way to be reminded that the post is in the queue.

Comment: "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening" is misleading.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt then I guess it's better to request updating the message, informing the editor that the question is already on the Reopen review queue and will be affected by all further edits, rather than unchecking the checkbox.

Comment: *This isn't what happens, at least with the current closure system.* Yes, that's indeed what happens. What that paragraph is talking about is if the question *prior to closure* was not closeable (i.e. the closure was incorrect), the review will indeed only show the minor edit (as that was the only one made after closure). It says, *One major place where this ends up becoming a problem is if one believes that a question in its current state doesn't violate any site rules, but there are some minor grammar or formatting edits that are necessary.*